# Simultaneous variable assignment and printing

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I was wondering if there was a way to assign a value and print the value to the console succinctly.

```
x <- 1:5; x
```

This is how I would presently do this, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it in one statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try:

```
(x <- 1:5)
```

or

```
print(x <- 1:5)
```

though that won't work for things like

```
(names(x) <- letters[1:5])
```

though for that specific example you can do:

```
(x <- setNames(x, letters[1:5]))
```

Comment: Didn't expect it but `("names<-"(x, letters[1:5]))` prints `x` with its names.

Comment: @alexis_laz, but unfortunately that doesn't actually set the names for `x`; I think in order for the black magic to work you have to use the `names(x) <- ...` form; or I guess you could do `(x <- "names<-"(x, letters[1:5]))` which is interesting because this gives you a generic mechanism for other replacement methods that don't have a function like `setNames`.

Comment: Hm, I looked into what you said and I got confused.. E.g. see this `x = 1; y = c(1,2); "names<-"(x, "x"); "names<-"(y, c("y1", "y2")); x; y`; `x` does not get a "names" attribute while `y` does. If `x` is named with `names(x) <- ..` then `"names<-"(x, ..)` does change its "names".

Comment: @alexis_laz, I'm afraid I still don't get any names being set for either `x` or `y` with your code.  If I try `names(x) <- "a"; "names<-"(x, "x"); x`, I still get the original names on `x` (i.e. "a") as well.

Comment: Please see this other **[SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022772/why-is-a-length-one-vector-initially-at-nam2)** for more details on the differences @alexis_laz and I were seeing here.