# Why is a length one vector initially at NAM(2)?

Tags: r

I stumbled across this behavior:

```
x <- 1:5
> tracemem(x)
[1] "<0x12145b7a8>"
> "names<-"(x, letters[1:5])
a b c d e 
1 2 3 4 5 
> x
a b c d e 
1 2 3 4 5  
> y <- 1L
> tracemem(y)
[1] "<0x12587ed68>"
> "names<-"(y,letters[1])
tracemem[0x12587ed68 -> 0x12587efa8]: 
a 
1
> y
[1] 1
```

when trying to help someone [figure out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22003697/324364) [why](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14938892#14938892) in the former case the vector's names are being modified but in the latter they are not.

Clearly, the length one vector is being copied, while the length 5 vector is being modified in place:

```
> x <- 1:5
> y <- 1L
> .Internal(inspect(x))
@121467490 13 INTSXP g0c3 [MARK,NAM(1)] (len=5, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5
> .Internal(inspect(y))
@1258d74d8 13 INTSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
```

Why does the length one vector start out its existence with its NAMED property incremented to 2?

In response to @nograpes comment below, I'm seeing this on OS X 10.7.5 and R 3.0.2.

Comment: Well, other than a possible assumption on the part of the writer that scalars would never get a name assigned...

Comment: In Windows, I cannot duplicate this: the vector `x`'s names are *not* modified in place.

Comment: @nograpes The plot thickens. I added my OS and R version to the question. I find it odd that there would be differences between OS for this...

Comment: BTW, since the code `"names<-"(something)` is wickedly twisted at best, why are you doing this?  `names(y)<−letters[1]` works just fine.  -- I can reproduce your results for `x` and `y` under Win7,R 302.

Comment: Okay, this is weird too: In Windows 7 x64, under RStudio 0.98.501, and R 3.0.2, the names are *not* modified in place, but under plain R, they *are* modified in place.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That was simply the context in which it came up and where I noticed the difference. Either way, the question is why the difference in the NAMED property, which is the source of the copying...

Comment: maybe relevant: if you initialize `y` to `1:1` or `c(1L)`, you get the same behavior as you do for `x`. Although `identical(1L, 1:1)` and `identical(1L, c(1L))`.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It's not wickedly twisted, just calling the replacement function directly to help to isolate the operation.

Comment: @flodel,  looks like there are identical identicals and unidentical identicals (with no apologies to Rumsfeld).

Comment: So am I the only one for whom: `rm(x); x <- 1:5; "names<-"(x, letters[1:5]); x` produces: `[1] 1 2 3 4 5`?  This is on windows 7 64 "R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)".

Comment: @BrodieG It sounded like nograpes might have seen the same thing on that platform. See if it changes between the R GUI, RStudio, command line, etc.

Comment: I missed @nograpes comment.  I can confirm what he saw; it works weird under RStudio, but okay in command line.

Comment: And how on earth does RStudio have any impact on this?

Comment: @BrodieG [Here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559387/operator-in-rstudio-and-r/15559956#15559956) ;)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, fascinating

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Matthew Dowle asked the same question [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-td4103326.html), and Peter Dalgaard answered thusly:

> This is tricky business... I'm not quite sure I'll get it right, but
>   let's try
>
> When you are assigning a constant, the value you assign is already
>   part of the assignment expression, so if you want to modify it, you
>   must duplicate. So `NAMED==2` on `z <- 1` is basically to prevent you from
>   accidentally "changing the value of 1". If it weren't, then you could
>   get bitten by code like `for(i in 1:2) {z <- 1; if(i==1) z[1] <- 2}`.

This may seem exotic, but really, the rationale is exactly the same as it is for incrementing `NAM` to `2` *whenever* doing an assignment of the form `x <- y`.

[As discussed here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-ints.html#Rest-of-header), R supports a "call by value" illusion to avoid at least some unnecessary copying of objects. So, for instance, `x <- y` really just binds the symbol `x` to `y`'s value. The danger of doing that without further precautions, though, is that subsequent modification of `x` would also modify `y` and any other symbols linked to `y`. R gets around this by marking `y`'s value as "linked to" (by setting it's `NAM=2`) as soon as it is assigned (or even potentially assigned) to another symbol.

When you do `x <- 1`, the `1` is more or less just another `y` whose value is being linked to the symbol `x` by the assignment expression. It's just that the potential for mischief arising from subsequent modification of `x`'s value (recalling that at this point, it's just a reference to the value of `1`!) is awful to imagine. But, as always with assignments of one symbol to another, R sets `NAM=2`, and no modifications without actual copying are allowed.

The reason `x <- 1:10` is different (as are `x <- 1:1`, `x <- c(1)`, `x <- seq(1)`, and even `x <- -1`) is that the RHS is actually a function call, and the result of that function call is what's being assigned to `x`. In these cases, the value of `x` is not just a reference to the value of some other symbol; modifying `x` won't potentially change the value of some other symbol, so there is no need to set `NAM=2`.

Comment: I think I might just barely follow this. Would you be able to elaborate on exactly what he's implying might go wrong in that for loop...? I think I get it, but it seems almost too crazy to be true.

Comment: Is Peter suggesting that without this, `z[1] <- 2` could actually change the value of `1` to `2`? Because `1` is intimately linked with `z` due to the first assignment in the loop?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yep. I'll work up an edit to my answer that aims to clarify that and to answer joran's query.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks; That was how I recalled understanding that thread when it originally took place, but seeing it here like that made my head hurt again with the potential implications if it were so.